# how to know on which line of the file an IOexception has happened

Tags: java, exception

In my program i want to read from a text file. the data in my files are numbers which are separated by space . i will convert them to integer in my program. I want to catch the exception if the data read from the file is not number. I want to know exactly in which line of the file the error has happened(the data is not number). I know i should catch the NumberFormatException exception but do not no how to find the line of the exception.
here is a bits of code:

```
try 
{ 
  //...using Bufferreader ...some code here
  while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null ) 
  {
    String[] term = strLine.split(" ");  
    //for now i just work with the first element of the array
    int num = Integer.parseInt(term[0]); 
    //....some code here
  }
  in.close();
}
catch (NumberFormatException eg)
{
  System.out.println("Error: there is a problem in line ..? " );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
int line = 0;
try 
{ 
  //...using Bufferreader ...some code here
  while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null ) 
  {
    line ++;
    String[] term = strLine.split(" ");  
    //for now i just work with the first element of the array
    int num = Integer.parseInt(term[0]); 
    //....some code here
  }
  in.close();
}
catch (NumberFormatException eg)
{
  System.out.println("Error: there is a problem in line " + line );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int num = Integer.parseInt(term[0]);
```

Above line will throw NumberFormatException when arguments will not be numbers.